# Add TICoreDataSync to ios/mac project

Tags: ios, macos, ticoredatasync

I'm trying to add TICoreDataSync to my project, my plan is o sync core data between 2 apps (mac and ios).
i try to follow the tutorials ([for ios](http://timisted.github.com/TICoreDataSync/ios-tutorial.html),[for mac](http://timisted.github.com/TICoreDataSync/mac-tutorial.html)) but it seem to be old, the described folder are not the same as the last version in the repo.

can any help me? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We just released version 1.0.2 of the framework and have updated the example apps and tutorials, along with a bunch of documentation. Check them out on the project wiki and let me know if you run into any trouble by opening an issue on the project's issues page. https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync/wiki